# How to use Vacuum in FMDB iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

As the title, how to use Vacuum to shrink a SQLite database using FMDB?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all your support
I've found out the answer : [database executeUpdate:@"vacuum"];

Answer (score -2):

1.Database Updating

I have a single database controller — VSDatabaseController in my latest app — that talks to SQLite via FMDB.
FMDB differentiates between updates and queries. To update the database the app calls:

```
-[VSDatabaseController runDatabaseBlockInTransaction:(VSDatabaseUpdateBlock)databaseBlock]
```

VSDatabaseUpdateBlock is simple:

```
typedef void (^VSDatabaseUpdateBlock)(FMDatabase *database);
```

runDatabaseBlockInTransaction is also simple:

```
- (void)runDatabaseBlockInTransaction:(VSDatabaseUpdateBlock)databaseBlock {
    dispatch_async(self.serialDispatchQueue, ^{
        @autoreleasepool {
            [self beginTransaction];
            databaseBlock(self.database);
            [self endTransaction];
        }
    });
}
```

Here’s a simple example of a call to update the database:
SELECT ALL

```
- (void)emptyTagsLookupTableForNote:(VSNote *)note {
    NSString *uniqueID = note.uniqueID;
    [self runDatabaseBlockInTransaction:^(FMDatabase *database) {
        [database executeUpdate:
            @"delete from tagsNotesLookup where noteUniqueID = ?;", uniqueID];
    }];
}

[self.database executeUpdate:
    @"CREATE INDEX if not exists noteUniqueIDIndex on tagsNotesLookup (noteUniqueID);"];
```

2. Database Fetching

   To fetch objects, the app calls:

SELECT ALL

```
-[VSDatabaseController runFetchForClass:(Class)databaseObjectClass 
                             fetchBlock:(VSDatabaseFetchBlock)fetchBlock 
                      fetchResultsBlock:(VSDatabaseFetchResultsBlock)fetchResultsBlock];
These two lines do much of the work:
SELECT ALL
FMResultSet *resultSet = fetchBlock(self.database);
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self databaseObjectsWithResultSet:resultSet 
                                                       class:databaseObjectClass];
```

A database fetch using FMDB returns an FMResultSet. With that resultSet you can step through and create model objects.

3.Keeping Objects in Memory

FMResultSet *resultSet = [self.database executeQuery:@"select uniqueID from some_table"];

4.Web APIs

```
- (void)uploadNote:(VSNote *)note {
    VSNoteAPICall *apiCall = [[VSNoteAPICall alloc] initWithNote:[note detachedCopy]];
    [self enqueueAPICall:apiCall];
}
```

5.Handling Web API Return Values

```
VSNote *cachedNote = [self.mapTable objectForKey:downloadedNote.uniqueID];
```

6.Database Migration

```
[self.database executeUpdate:@"CREATE TABLE if not exists tags "
    "(uniqueID TEXT UNIQUE, name TEXT, deleted INTEGER, deletedModificationDate DATE);"];
```

I hope, it will help you.